# Bash script is not reverting the name on timeout

Tags: bash, shell

I have a small Bash script to rename tmux window for [heroku cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and rename it back when I close the `heroku` session.

```
heroku(){
  windowname=$(tmux display-message -p '#W')
  tmux rename-window "heroku $(echo "$@")"
  command heroku "$@"
  tmux rename-window "$windowname"
}
```

But `heroku` has a timeout feature, if it stays too long it will close the connection.
In this case, my script will not revert the name of tmux window.

How to catch that timeout and revert the name of tmux window?

Comment: Do you have `set -x`? Can you use `trap`?

Comment: The optimal method would be via custom **[signal handler](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html)** that uses `sigaction()` whenever `SIGHUP` is triggered.

Comment: @tripleee, looks like `trap "{ tmux rename-window "$windowname" }" EXIT` does the trick

Comment: @ceving `tmux rename-window "heroku $@"` doesn't work

Comment: The very *purpose* of `"$@"` is to preserve any quoting. But here, you want everything collapsed into one quoted string; that's what `$*` does. (This is unusual enough that we sometimes abbreviate to "never use `$*`" but this is one of the cases where it's exactly what you want.)

Comment: @tripleee, `$*` did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `tripleee` and `ceving` I rewrote my script to this:

```
heroku(){
  windowname=$(tmux display-message -p '#W')
 
  trap "{ tmux rename-window "$windowname" }" EXIT

  tmux rename-window "heroku $*"

  command heroku "$@"

  tmux rename-window "$windowname"
}
```